# Why is my game stuttering?

Tags: pc, rainbow-six-siege

Rainbow Six Siege stutters every few seconds or so. My PC is definitely more than capable to run the game well but I have no idea why it still stutters. It has happened to me in other games, like CSGO. I have run virus scans and updated Windows.

In this context, stuttering is when R6S freezes for about 0.5-1 second every 5-10 seconds.

I have tried [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=739436571) to fix my issue, including some of the comments' suggestions, like uninstalling Microsoft C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. Even running Anti-Virus and Anti-Malware software does not help.

My PC's specs are as follows:

> Processor: Intel i7-7700k (4.4 GHz on an EVO 212 Air Cooler)
>
> Graphics Card: EVGA GeForce GTX 1080 FTW ACX 3.0
>
> RAM: Corsair Vegeance LPX - 16 GB/3200 MHz
>
> Storage: 120 GB SSD + 5 TB Western Digital Professional at 7200 RPM
>
> Monitor: ViewSonic XG2700 - 4K @ 60 Hz with a 5ms Delay (3840x2160)
>
> Power Supply: Corsair CX850M (850 Watts)
>
> Operating System: Windows 10 Home Premium 64-Bit

Comment: Good question. I had exactly the same problem ten years ago with Bioshock and I never did find a solution. Some people claimed the problem was caused by the game switching between cores on a multi-core CPU.

Comment: If you have W10 Game Booster turned on, try to turn it off? Maybe that works.

Comment: Have you recently updated your drivers, especially graphics drivers? I know I hadn't played in a while and recently went back and was given a notification that my graphics driver needed to updated for the newest content.

Comment: @n_palum Tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Is VSync disabled? If not, try that. I've noticed improvements in random games by turning VSync off.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I've tried VSync on and off, but it doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Possible dumb question, but what is your hard drive like? What is the current storage vs. total capacity and is it a physical drive or an SSD. That would be for both the drive that Siege is on as well as the Drive that has your OS installed.

Comment: @Malco You may be on to something. I have a 5 TB 7200 RPM hard drive (where I store most of my games) and a 120 GB SSD drive for my OS, but I only have about 200 GB left on my hard drive. Should I delete unplayed games from my hard drive?

Comment: Do you have/play any other high-end games on that system, any issues ?

Comment: @CamouflagedCow You may want to try cleaning up some space on your hard drive. General Wisdom is to have between 10%-5% of hard drive space free, and you are right around that limit. It is unlikely that hard drive fragmentation is causing the stutters, especially since [Win10 defrags automatically on a schedule](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/defragment-hard-drive-windows), but it is worth a shot. If you manually clear out a lot of space on your HDD (Not SSD) then it would be a good idea to manually defrag it (see link above). Let me know if this helps, if so I will write it as an answer.

Comment: @Malco I did an entire optimization on my hard drive and left about 800 GB of storage left. I still stutter on R6S, but not any other games that I am aware of it.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Hmm, Not too sure what it could be. On the upside, you are going to have your computer running in tip-top optimal shape trying all these fixes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the most common cause of this (provided the hardware is beefy enough to support the game, which seems to be the case here) is the defragmentation of the drives. I know modern Windows OS versions claim to do this automatically, but there needs to be sufficient free space on the disk in order for this to occur. Personally I find that it's not good enough, and often perform the task manually every few months or so, especially after installing and deleting large files (usually games in my case, some with several thousand files or more).

One other thing to try is to look at your paging (swap) space. Contrary to what some think, the swap space *can* be too large, or if the paging file is on a heavily fragmented drive, that can cause issues too (unless it was there when the disk was formatted, it shouldn't be fragmented at all).

Hope that helps.

Comment: How do I check the page file? I did an entire optimization and left about 800 GB free so it is not the hard drive.

Comment: Right click on start button, select `Control Panel`. Then `System and Security` then `System`. Then on the left panel, `Advanced System Settings`. Then under the `Performance` frame, click `Settings`, then select the `Advanced` tab. It will show virtual memory (same thing.) I've always used the rule of 1-2x the physical memory for swap/virtual memory, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: My page file is default at 9216 MB, but I have 16 GB of RAM. Should I change it to 16384 MB?

Comment: I would -- but I don't know if it would completely mitigate your performance issues. It should improve it somewhat though.

Comment: Apparently my hard drive didn't have any allocated page file size, so I set it to system managed, which brought it up to12160 MB.

Comment: Does the performance seem better? Having no virtual memory is usually pretty bad for performance.

Comment: The stutters seem to be less of an issue, but they are still there.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty because you have helped me out the most and had a good answer. However, the question is still open.

Comment: Thanks -- another thing to look at possibly is the antialiasing. Some games do more intensive GPU activity than others, perhaps try turning down (or off) the anti-aliasing (or the tri/bilinear filtering) to see if that improves performance. Shadows and water graphics also have a major impact in games.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I initially got the game.

Could I ask, do you have a similar issue when playing Fallout 4? I had this problem with Rainbow Six Siege and Fallout 4, drove me nuts.

I did a lot of tinkering, I spent around 5 days tweaking, modifying, resetting etc, nothing worked.

I remember I left it for about 6 or so months and magically it was working. In this period I did the following things:

Did a completely fresh install of my Graphics card drivers, including removing any Nvidia software from my PC.Then did a fresh install of everything, specifically getting all of my software from the NVidia site instead of the discs provided. I would recommend getting the installers beforehand.

Re-installed Steam: Took out my D drive with all my games onto be triple sure I didn't delete them.

I would recommend trying the above, I can remember the frustration, hopefully, you find a solution, do remember to take a break.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's only one game that's causing the issue, and you've most likely installed it on the HDD, try reinstalling on your SSD and see if that improves things.
With the machine specs you have,that 5Tb HDD is holding you back.
I'd recommend investing in an SSD dedicated to games.
You can pick up a SanDisk 240Gb SSD for less than £80 in the UK ($90 in the US) on Amazon.

Answer (score -1):

interesting. and a decent rig too. swap file recommendation is 1.5 ram size. yes 24g is big and debatable but thats what i have with no problems. defrag properly and regularly of course. not the SSD. if it's only one or two games that are giving you trouble it's probably the games themselves. some games just won't play nice. tweak the graphics a little. you probably won't notice visually. 
or try the old favorite turn off your AV software. 
or is something big and hungry running in the background?